# How to solve this convergence problem?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$
(\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sum_{k = 1}^{n} {\|{x_k}\|} < \infty} ) \Longrightarrow (\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sum_{k = 1}^{n} {\|{x_k}\|}^2 < \infty} )
$$

Comment: $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is an obvious counterexample.

Comment: so how does one prove that if a series is convergent, then the sum of the squares is convergent too?

Comment: By using $\|x_n\|^2 \leq \|x_n\|$ for $n \gg 0$, provided $\sum \|x_n\|$ converges. Note that you need absolute convergence.

Comment: If I edit the question would you mind giving a complete proof? Please...

Comment: $\|x_n\|^2 \leq \|x_n\|$ for $n \gg 0$ is actually the complete proof. You should now think about two things: Why does this inequality hold for $ n \gg 0$? Then check that this implies the assertion by comparison criteria.

Comment: So why does it hold? Because the sequence converges to zero, right? I can prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sum_{k = 1}^{n} {\|{x_k}\|} < \infty}  \Longrightarrow \exists N.n \ge N \Rightarrow {\|{x_n}\|} \lt 1
$$
$$
{\|{x_n}\|} \lt 1 \Rightarrow {\|{x_n}\|}^2 \lt {\|{x_n}\|}
$$
so by the comparison test
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sum_{k = N}^{N+n} {\|{x_k}\|} < \infty}  \Longrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} {\sum_{k = N}^{N+n} {\|{x_k}\|}^2 < \infty} 
$$
the finite set of terms with suffix $\lt N$ obviously has no bearing on the convergence of the infinite series

Answer (score 1):

If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers such that $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ converges, then  $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0\implies$ for an $\epsilon<1$ $\exists N,\ $ such that $\forall n\ge N$, $a_n\le \epsilon\implies \forall n\ge N$, $a_n^2\le \epsilon a_n$, then $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n^2\le \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n^2+\epsilon\sum_{n\ge N}a_n<\infty$